# Creating simple Object pool in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, design-patterns

I've been reading many articles on how we can improve android app performance by reducing GC work of reclaiming unused object and heap thrashing. Now the question arises:

1) Is it possible to reduce the work done by GC ?

2) Some people say the DVM GC is so efficient that trying to “work around” its performance characteristics will just make things worse.

So, the "work around" could be creating Object Pool of fixed size where objects are pre-allocated when the pool is created. When application needs an object, it request from pool instead of creating one.

Then, I encountered a class in `support.v4` library in android [Pools.SynchronizedPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/Pools.html)  which I think can serve the purpose instead of the previous ObjectPool design pattern.

But, now how to use it in my simple android app just to test the performance.

Comment: Don't you find a bit strange to first explain that you read articles on reducing GC work; to then ask: "is it possible to reduce GC work"? Besides: I think that those "other people" have a good point. Independent if you are using Oracle hotspot or the Dalvik VM ... in the end; all systems are optimized for certain usage patterns. **Breaking** these patterns can result in making a lot of changes (that probably make your application more complex; ergo harder to maintain and extend) ... for no real effect.  So: only optimize if you are really having a problem; and then: measure first!

Comment: One way to reduce GC in a game, for example, is to avoid calling 'new' within your update & render loops.  Instead, preallocate the necessary objects during setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Object pool to reduce GC, You can use it like this https://github.com/ChenQingZhen/AndroidObjectPool